# How to modify an existing Attribute's base code

Tags: acumatica

In the timesheet code there is an attribute called PXWeekSelector2:

[image]

What I need to know is how to modify the code of this attribute in a customization project to increase the weekListCount variable to go over 1000 (ours is actually 800, from the year 2005 - which is why we've hit our limit).

Not sure how to override or modify an existing attribute.  Any help would be appreciated.

Updated 4/28:
If I look at the PXWeekSelector2Attribute in the source code, this is what I see.  I don't see any method like 'Prefetch':

```
namespace PX.Objects.EP
{
public class PXWeekSelector2Attribute : PXWeekSelectorAttribute
{
    public PXWeekSelector2Attribute();

    public static int GetNextWeekID(PXGraph graph, int weekID);
    public static int GetNextWeekID(PXGraph graph, DateTime date);
    public static DateTime GetWeekEndDate(PXGraph graph, int weekId);
    public static int GetWeekID(PXGraph graph, DateTime date);
    public static WeekInfo GetWeekInfo(PXGraph graph, int weekId);
    public static DateTime GetWeekStartDate(PXGraph graph, int weekId);
    public static bool IsCustomWeek(PXGraph graph);
    protected override IEnumerable GetAllRecords();

    public class FullWeekList
    {
        public FullWeekList();

        public static List<EPWeekRaw> Weeks();
    }
    public class WeekInfo
    {
        public WeekInfo();

        public DayInfo Mon { get; }
        public DayInfo Tue { get; }
        public DayInfo Wed { get; }
        public DayInfo Thu { get; }
        public DayInfo Fri { get; }
        public DayInfo Sat { get; }
        public DayInfo Sun { get; }
        public Dictionary<DayOfWeek, DayInfo> Days { get; }

        public void AddDayInfo(DateTime date);
        public bool IsValid(DateTime date);
    }
    public class DayInfo
    {
        public DayInfo(DateTime? date);

        public DateTime? Date { get; }
        public bool Enabled { get; }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create your own version of the `PXWeekSelector2Attribute` where you will change the `FullWeekList.Definition.Prefetch` method to read as many records as you need like below

```
public void Prefetch()
{
    DateTime curentDay = this._stratDay;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int year;
        if (curentDay.AddDays(-3.0).Year < curentDay.Year && PXDateTimeInfo.GetWeekNumber(curentDay) > 1)
        {
            year = curentDay.AddYears(-1).Year;
        }
        else
        {
            year = curentDay.Year;
        }
        EPWeekRaw rawWeek = EPWeekRaw.ToEPWeekRaw(new PXWeekSelectorAttribute.EPWeek
        {
            WeekID = new int?(year * 100 + PXDateTimeInfo.GetWeekNumber(curentDay))
        });
        this._weeks.Add(rawWeek);
        curentDay = curentDay.AddDays(7.0);
    }
}
```

and copy almost all other methods and members of `PXWeekSelector2Attribute` and change them to work with your attribute's methods

```
    protected override IEnumerable GetAllRecords()
    {
        if (PXWeekSelectorCustomAttribute.IsCustomWeek(this._Graph))
        {
            return (from _ in (PXResultset<EPCustomWeek>)PXSelectBase<EPCustomWeek, PXSelect<EPCustomWeek>.Config>.Select(this._Graph, null).AsEnumerable<PXResult<EPCustomWeek>>()
            select EPWeekRaw.ToEPWeekRaw((EPCustomWeek)_)).ToList<EPWeekRaw>();
        }
        return PXWeekSelectorCustomAttribute.FullWeekList.Weeks();
    }
```

And the last thing will be to overwrite the `PXWeekSelector2Attribute` with your `PXWeekSelectorCustomAttribute` using `CacheAttached` whereever you need.

Comment: See my additions to the original post.  One other thing - I don't know how to recreate that attribute - do I need to inherit the PXWeekSelectorAttribute if I re-create the PXWeekSelector2Attribute?   The discrepancy between what I see in the source code and what you posted here is very confusing.